# Why is my python server refusing requests from my js code?

Tags: javascript, python, http

im trying to make a python api and send requests to it from js (all locally). im getting this response from my js code:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async getRes (C:\Users\omerg\Desktop\Dev\VSCode Projects\python js link\jsApp.js:6:26) {cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8080
    at TC…Wrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1…, stack: 'TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (…VSCode Projects\python js link\jsApp.js:6:26)', message: 'fetch failed'}
```

when i connect to the same address through the browser it works fine, but not from my js code. however, i dont think the problem is with my js code as when i try to run the same code but instead of the python server i run a similar js server, it works correctly. my python code is:

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import json

def open_server(handler, PORT=8080):
    httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), handler)
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()

class api_handler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({"res1": "res1"}).encode("utf-8"))

open_server(api_handler, PORT=8080)
```

my js code is:

```
const getRes = async res => {
    console.log("getting res")
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    })
        if (response.status === 200){
            console.log(response.status)
            const responseJson = await response.json()
            console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson))
            return responseJson
        }
        console.log(response.status)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

getRes("res1")
```

the js server code i used to test:

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req)
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/json'})
    const obj = {
        name: '张三',
        age: 18
    }
    res.write(JSON.stringify(obj))
    res.end()
}).listen(8080)
```

would love any help as i have no idea whats wrong..

Comment: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8080` is saying there's nothing listening to your request. You might want to try `"0"` or `"::1"` or `"localhost"` instead of that empty string in `TCPServer`.

Comment: why are you setting `"Content-Type"` header in a GET request? Not sure that's the issue, it may be a CORS issue, what error do you get in the browser developer tools?

Comment: @AKX
tried all three, localhost gives the same error and 0 and ::1 give an getaddrinfo failed error

Comment: @JaromandaX good point, got confused with the "accept" header. changed it, although i tried both commented out the headers and passing an empty headers object and its the same.
and if you mean error in the browser when i try to access it from the browser there isn't one, just the js code (im using nodejs)
also tried to copy the fetch request from chrome (which worked in the browser), gave the same error

Comment: `when i try to access it from the browser there isn't one` so it succeeds? Or are you not looking in the right place to see network info?

Comment: @JaromandaX in the browser, yes. but copying the exact same request as a fetch and running it does not
also wdym "the right place to see network info"? im looking in the network tab of devtools, no idea if thats what you mean (also i know it succeeds because the browser displays a correct response anyway)

Comment: OK, let me get this straight. The python server works fine if you make a request from a browser, it fails if you make a request from ... some unnamed source?

Comment: @JaromandaX ill summarize:
python server works correctly for the browser,
does not work for the js client
however, js client works correctly for the js server